# Azure Function: how can I improve the Unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, xunit.net, azure-blob-trigger

Azure function based on .Net core 3.1. Triggered when a file is uploaded into the Blob container. Any files uploaded to Azure Blob Storage are compressed, and the database is updated.

Below is my business logic

```
public partial class FileProcessingServiceFacade : IFileProcessingServiceFacade
{
    public async Task<string> ProcessAsync(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
    {   
        AppDbContext.FileRecords.Add(new FileRecords { ... });
        AppDbContext.SaveChanges();

        return await Task.FromResult($"success");
    }
}

public partial class FileProcessingServiceFacade : ServiceBase<FileProcessingServiceFacade>
{
    public FileProcessingServiceFacade(AppDbContext appDbContext, IOptions<AppConfigurator> configurator) 
        : base(appDbContext, configurator) { }
}
```

I am using xUnit and MOQ for unit testing and below is my unit test

```
[Fact]
public void ProcessAsync()
{
    var filename = "fileName.csv";
    var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
    var log = Mock.Of<ILogger>();
    var executionContext = Mock.Of<ExecutionContext>();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Testing")
    .Options;
    var appDbContext = new AppDbContext(options);
    var appSettings = new AppConfigurator(){ ... };
    IOptions<AppConfigurator> configurator = Options.Create(appSettings);

    var target = new FileProcessingServiceFacade(appDbContext, configurator);
    var actual = target.ProcessAsync(stream, filename, log, executionContext);
    Assert.True(appDbContext.FileRecords.FirstAsync<FileRecords>().Result.FileName.Equals(filename));
    Assert.True(actual.Result.Equals("success"));
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

I am trying to improve the code quality of the unit testing and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Jeff Hollan shared a functions test helper project but it's not been updated in a little while. Maybe something within the project might help though: https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Application test involves one or more **external systems**, below are the sample points which you need to be aware while have unit testing*

1. *Tests may fail if you ae connecting your application with **Remote System** or **External System**.*
2. *You need to call the external system directly.*
3. *Accessing external system may have an effect on the performance of your tests.*

*Also, As suggested by [BrettMiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12040634/brettmiller) you can go through the sample of [Azure functions Test fixture](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper).*

[image]

[image]